# jQuery datatables collapses by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

My table loads by default like this:
[image]

I have to resize the browser in order to make header expand:
[image]

And then click one of the headers(sorting) to expand all rows:
[image]

Is there something missing, but I couldn't figure out a reason why collapse is default.

js + handlebars file:

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        url: /some/path
    });

    var MyRowView = Reporting.RowView.extend({
        template: _.template($("#row-template").html())
    });

    var MyTableView = Reporting.TableView.extend({
        el: $(".report"),
        header: _.template($("#header-template").html()),
        table: _.template($( "#table-template").html()),
        RowView: MyRowView
    });

    var mycollection = new MyCollection();
    
    var tableView = new MyTableView({
        collection: mycollection
    });
    
    mycollection.fetch();
    
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="header-template">
    <tr>
        <th>{{i18n "Assignment"}}</th>
        <th>{{i18n "Status"}}</th>
        <th>{{i18n "Success"}}</th>
        <th>{{i18n "Score"}}</th>
        <th>{{i18n "Comments"}}</th>
        <th>{{i18n "Rating"}}</th>
    </tr>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="row-template">
    <td><%= resourceName %></td>
    <td><%= completionStatus %></td>
    <td><%= successStatus %></td>
    <td><%= score %></td>
    <td><%= noComments %></td>
    <td><%= noRatings %></td>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="table-template">
    <table id="table-id" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>

<div class="report">
    {{include this resourceType="/path/to/bootstraptable"}}
</div>
{{includeClientLib categories="category.of.js.file" }}
```

Comment: No code means no help buddy. However, one thing that comes up to mind is the function event.preventDefault(). Maybe try that?

Comment: Add you javascript so we can see how you are configuring your table.

Comment: Sorry, just pasted some snippet, it's not a working one because it relies on some other platform to stick them together.

Comment: It might have something to do with your `<tbody>` being hidden on page load? Also, you might want to look into the DataTables `autoWidth` option and see how you have it set.... if you have it set.

Answer (score 0):

**CAUSE**

Most likely this occurs because your table is hidden when DataTables initialization occurs. However I don't see DataTables initialization code in your JavaScript code.

**SOLUTION**

You need to run the following function once your table becomes visible.

```
$('#table-id').DataTable().columns.adjust();
```

From the [columns.adjust()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) page in the manual:

> Call it when the table becomes visible if hidden when initialised (for example in a tab) or when the data changes significantly.

**LINKS**

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solution to the most common problems with jQuery DataTables when table is initially hidden.